# How can I open a modal from views.py in django? Is there any way?

Tags: django

I have a django application. when a user clicks the submit button two modals should be shown one after another each has to do different functions in views.py in my django app. I am trying to write the code but the problem is not easy and I have looked everywhere and couldn't get the answer.

I have to write the code in the following way:

views.py

```
def submit(request):
   #first modal should pop up which has two options.
   #second modal should pop up which also has a two options.
```

and when the user clicks any of the buttons each should also call the different function in views.py.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


 <button class="btn btn-danger custom" style="position:absolute; left:800px; top:180px;" type="submit">Update the data</button>
                    
                
# user clicks a button in form and modal should pop up
# then 2 modals should pop up
# the first modal has two buttons 
# when user clicks the update button the function in the views should be called and also 2nd modal 
should pop up


     <!--modal 1-->
        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="UpdateModal" role="dialog"
             tabindex="-1">


        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update Changes</h5>
                    <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
#when user clicks update button another modal should pop up as well as 
another function in the views should be called.

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Opening modal windows needs to be done in frontend code, not in the backend Django views.py file.

Comment: Hint: `javascript`, `ajax`

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's been answered. If you have a new question, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by using the modal system from [the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), you can check the [live demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo)

In your template use a condition with [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) **if first condition** show modal 1, else **show modal 2**, just make sure you have 2 different ID for the modal so they open distinctly